Can Not Receive Offered Verifiable Credential From Issuer - credo-ts
To issue a verifiable credential to a specific holder, I send a credential offer to the holder that is connected beforehand by DIDComm but the holder cannot receive/accept the credential offer.
I use VON network and ensure that issuer DID, credential schema and definition is published on the ledger. Also, the code does not give any errors. Any help will be appreciated.
Here is my code:
Import statements:
import { AskarModule } from '@credo-ts/askar'
import {
  Agent,
  InitConfig,
  ConnectionEventTypes,
  ConnectionStateChangedEvent,
  WsOutboundTransport,
  HttpOutboundTransport,
  DidExchangeState,
  OutOfBandRecord,
  ConnectionsModule,
  V2CredentialProtocol, DidsModule, CredentialsModule,
  TypedArrayEncoder, KeyType,
  CredentialStateChangedEvent, CredentialEventTypes, CredentialState, AutoAcceptCredential
} from '@credo-ts/core'
import { agentDependencies, HttpInboundTransport } from '@credo-ts/node'
import { ariesAskar } from '@hyperledger/aries-askar-nodejs'
import {
  IndyVdrAnonCredsRegistry,
  IndyVdrIndyDidRegistrar,
  IndyVdrIndyDidResolver,
  IndyVdrModule
} from '@credo-ts/indy-vdr'
import { indyVdr } from '@hyperledger/indy-vdr-nodejs'
import { AnonCredsModule, LegacyIndyCredentialFormatService, AnonCredsCredentialFormatService } from '@credo-ts/anoncreds'
import { anoncreds } from '@hyperledger/anoncreds-nodejs'

Genesis transactions:
const genesis = [{"reqSignature":{},"txn":{"data":{"data":{"alias":"Node1","blskey":"4N8aUNHSgjQVgkpm8nhNEfDf6txHznoYREg9kirmJrkivgL4oSEimFF6nsQ6M41QvhM2Z33nves5vfSn9n1UwNFJBYtWVnHYMATn76vLuL3zU88KyeAYcHfsih3He6UHcXDxcaecHVz6jhCYz1P2UZn2bDVruL5wXpehgBfBaLKm3Ba","blskey_pop":"RahHYiCvoNCtPTrVtP7nMC5eTYrsUA8WjXbdhNc8debh1agE9bGiJxWBXYNFbnJXoXhWFMvyqhqhRoq737YQemH5ik9oL7R4NTTCz2LEZhkgLJzB3QRQqJyBNyv7acbdHrAT8nQ9UkLbaVL9NBpnWXBTw4LEMePaSHEw66RzPNdAX1","client_ip":"172.31.146.255","client_port":9702,"node_ip":"172.31.146.255","node_port":9701,"services":["VALIDATOR"]},"dest":"Gw6pDLhcBcoQesN72qfotTgFa7cbuqZpkX3Xo6pLhPhv"},"metadata":{"from":"Th7MpTaRZVRYnPiabds81Y"},"type":"0"},"txnMetadata":{"seqNo":1,"txnId":"fea82e10e894419fe2bea7d96296a6d46f50f93f9eeda954ec461b2ed2950b62"},"ver":"1"},
{"reqSignature":{},"txn":{"data":{"data":{"alias":"Node2","blskey":"37rAPpXVoxzKhz7d9gkUe52XuXryuLXoM6P6LbWDB7LSbG62Lsb33sfG7zqS8TK1MXwuCHj1FKNzVpsnafmqLG1vXN88rt38mNFs9TENzm4QHdBzsvCuoBnPH7rpYYDo9DZNJePaDvRvqJKByCabubJz3XXKbEeshzpz4Ma5QYpJqjk","blskey_pop":"Qr658mWZ2YC8JXGXwMDQTzuZCWF7NK9EwxphGmcBvCh6ybUuLxbG65nsX4JvD4SPNtkJ2w9ug1yLTj6fgmuDg41TgECXjLCij3RMsV8CwewBVgVN67wsA45DFWvqvLtu4rjNnE9JbdFTc1Z4WCPA3Xan44K1HoHAq9EVeaRYs8zoF5","client_ip":"172.31.146.255","client_port":9704,"node_ip":"172.31.146.255","node_port":9703,"services":["VALIDATOR"]},"dest":"8ECVSk179mjsjKRLWiQtssMLgp6EPhWXtaYyStWPSGAb"},"metadata":{"from":"EbP4aYNeTHL6q385GuVpRV"},"type":"0"},"txnMetadata":{"seqNo":2,"txnId":"1ac8aece2a18ced660fef8694b61aac3af08ba875ce3026a160acbc3a3af35fc"},"ver":"1"},
{"reqSignature":{},"txn":{"data":{"data":{"alias":"Node3","blskey":"3WFpdbg7C5cnLYZwFZevJqhubkFALBfCBBok15GdrKMUhUjGsk3jV6QKj6MZgEubF7oqCafxNdkm7eswgA4sdKTRc82tLGzZBd6vNqU8dupzup6uYUf32KTHTPQbuUM8Yk4QFXjEf2Usu2TJcNkdgpyeUSX42u5LqdDDpNSWUK5deC5","blskey_pop":"QwDeb2CkNSx6r8QC8vGQK3GRv7Yndn84TGNijX8YXHPiagXajyfTjoR87rXUu4G4QLk2cF8NNyqWiYMus1623dELWwx57rLCFqGh7N4ZRbGDRP4fnVcaKg1BcUxQ866Ven4gw8y4N56S5HzxXNBZtLYmhGHvDtk6PFkFwCvxYrNYjh","client_ip":"172.31.146.255","client_port":9706,"node_ip":"172.31.146.255","node_port":9705,"services":["VALIDATOR"]},"dest":"DKVxG2fXXTU8yT5N7hGEbXB3dfdAnYv1JczDUHpmDxya"},"metadata":{"from":"4cU41vWW82ArfxJxHkzXPG"},"type":"0"},"txnMetadata":{"seqNo":3,"txnId":"7e9f355dffa78ed24668f0e0e369fd8c224076571c51e2ea8be5f26479edebe4"},"ver":"1"},
{"reqSignature":{},"txn":{"data":{"data":{"alias":"Node4","blskey":"2zN3bHM1m4rLz54MJHYSwvqzPchYp8jkHswveCLAEJVcX6Mm1wHQD1SkPYMzUDTZvWvhuE6VNAkK3KxVeEmsanSmvjVkReDeBEMxeDaayjcZjFGPydyey1qxBHmTvAnBKoPydvuTAqx5f7YNNRAdeLmUi99gERUU7TD8KfAa6MpQ9bw","blskey_pop":"RPLagxaR5xdimFzwmzYnz4ZhWtYQEj8iR5ZU53T2gitPCyCHQneUn2Huc4oeLd2B2HzkGnjAff4hWTJT6C7qHYB1Mv2wU5iHHGFWkhnTX9WsEAbunJCV2qcaXScKj4tTfvdDKfLiVuU2av6hbsMztirRze7LvYBkRHV3tGwyCptsrP","client_ip":"172.31.146.255","client_port":9708,"node_ip":"172.31.146.255","node_port":9707,"services":["VALIDATOR"]},"dest":"4PS3EDQ3dW1tci1Bp6543CfuuebjFrg36kLAUcskGfaA"},"metadata":{"from":"TWwCRQRZ2ZHMJFn9TzLp7W"},"type":"0"},"txnMetadata":{"seqNo":4,"txnId":"aa5e817d7cc626170eca175822029339a444eb0ee8f0bd20d3b0b76e566fb008"},"ver":"1"}];


I stringfy the genesis transactions:
const stringfied_Json_genesis = genesis.map(txn => JSON.stringify(txn)).join('\n');

initializeBobAgent function definition to initialize the holder agent:
const initializeBobAgent = async () => {
  // Simple agent configuration. This sets some basic fields like the wallet
  // configuration and the label. It also sets the mediator invitation url,
  // because this is most likely required in a mobile environment.
  const config: InitConfig = {
    label: 'demo-agent-bob',
    walletConfig: {
      id: 'mainBob',
      key: 'demoagentbob00000000000000000000',
    },
    endpoints: ['http://localhost:3001'],
  }

  // A new instance of an agent is created here
  const agent = new Agent({
    config,
    modules: {
      askar: new AskarModule({ ariesAskar }),
      connections: new ConnectionsModule({ autoAcceptConnections: true }),
      indyVdr: new IndyVdrModule({
        indyVdr,
        networks: [
          {
            isProduction: false,
            indyNamespace: 'bcovrin:test',
            genesisTransactions: stringfied_Json_genesis,
            connectOnStartup: true,
          },
        ],
      }),
      anoncreds: new AnonCredsModule({
        registries: [new IndyVdrAnonCredsRegistry()],
        anoncreds,
      }),
      dids: new DidsModule({
        resolvers: [new IndyVdrIndyDidResolver()],
      }),
      credentials: new CredentialsModule({
        autoAcceptCredentials: AutoAcceptCredential.Always,
        credentialProtocols: [
          new V2CredentialProtocol({
            credentialFormats: [new LegacyIndyCredentialFormatService(), new AnonCredsCredentialFormatService()],
          }),
        ],
      }),
    },
    dependencies: agentDependencies

  })

  // Register a simple `WebSocket` outbound transport
  agent.registerOutboundTransport(new WsOutboundTransport())

  // Register a simple `Http` outbound transport
  agent.registerOutboundTransport(new HttpOutboundTransport())

  agent.registerInboundTransport(new HttpInboundTransport({ port: 3001 }))


  // Initialize the agent
  await agent.initialize()

  

  return agent
}

initializeAcmeAgent function definition to initialize the issuer agent:
const initializeAcmeAgent = async () => {
  // Simple agent configuration. This sets some basic fields like the wallet
  // configuration and the label.
  const config: InitConfig = {
    label: 'demo-agent-acma',
    walletConfig: {
      id: 'mainAcma',
      key: 'demoagentacma0000000000000000000',
    },
    endpoints: ['http://localhost:3002'],
    
  }

  // A new instance of an agent is created here
  const agent = new Agent({
    config,
    modules: {
      askar: new AskarModule({ ariesAskar }),
      connections: new ConnectionsModule({ autoAcceptConnections: true }),
      indyVdr: new IndyVdrModule({
        indyVdr,
        networks: [
          {
            isProduction: false,
            indyNamespace: 'bcovrin:test',
            genesisTransactions: stringfied_Json_genesis,
            connectOnStartup: true,
          },
        ],
      }),
      anoncreds: new AnonCredsModule({
        registries: [new IndyVdrAnonCredsRegistry()],
        anoncreds,
      }),
      dids: new DidsModule({
        registrars: [new IndyVdrIndyDidRegistrar()],
        resolvers: [new IndyVdrIndyDidResolver()],
      }),
      credentials: new CredentialsModule({
        autoAcceptCredentials: AutoAcceptCredential.Always,
        credentialProtocols: [
          new V2CredentialProtocol({
            credentialFormats: [new LegacyIndyCredentialFormatService(), new AnonCredsCredentialFormatService()],
          }),
        ],
      }),
    },
    dependencies: agentDependencies

  })

  // Register a simple `WebSocket` outbound transport
  agent.registerOutboundTransport(new WsOutboundTransport())

  // Register a simple `Http` outbound transport
  agent.registerOutboundTransport(new HttpOutboundTransport())

  // Register a simple `Http` inbound transport
  agent.registerInboundTransport(new HttpInboundTransport({ port: 3002 }))

  // Initialize the agent
  await agent.initialize()

  return agent
}

The function definition to create an invitation:
const createNewInvitation = async (agent: Agent) => {
  const outOfBandRecord = await agent.oob.createInvitation()

  return {
    invitationUrl: outOfBandRecord.outOfBandInvitation.toUrl({ domain: 'https://example.org' }),
    outOfBandRecord,
  }
}

The function definition to receive an invitation:
const receiveInvitation = async (agent: Agent, invitationUrl: string) => {
  const { outOfBandRecord } = await agent.oob.receiveInvitationFromUrl(invitationUrl)

  return outOfBandRecord
}

conID variable is defined to keep the connection ID of the agents:
let conID;

Function definition to set up an event listener for the issuer agent (Acme) listening responses to the connection invitation:
const setupConnectionListener = (agent: Agent, outOfBandRecord: OutOfBandRecord, cb: (...args: any) => void) => {
  agent.events.on<ConnectionStateChangedEvent>(ConnectionEventTypes.ConnectionStateChanged, ({ payload }) => {
    if (payload.connectionRecord.outOfBandId !== outOfBandRecord.id) return
    if (payload.connectionRecord.state === DidExchangeState.Completed) {
      // the connection is now ready for usage in other protocols!
      console.log(`Connection for out-of-band id ${outOfBandRecord.id} completed`)

      // Custom business logic can be included here
      // In this example we can send a basic message to the connection, but
      // anything is possible
      cb()
      conID = payload.connectionRecord.id

      // We exit the flow
      
    }
  })
}

Event listener for the holder agent (Bob) listening credential offers:
const setupCREDListener = (agent: Agent) => {
  agent.events.on<CredentialStateChangedEvent>(CredentialEventTypes.CredentialStateChanged, async ({ payload }) => {
    console.log("EVENT FIRED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
    switch (payload.credentialRecord.state) {
      case CredentialState.OfferReceived:
        console.log('received a credential')
        // custom logic here
        await agent.credentials.acceptOffer({ credentialRecordId: payload.credentialRecord.id })
        break
      case CredentialState.Done:
        console.log(`Credential for credential id ${payload.credentialRecord.id} is accepted`)
        // For demo purposes we exit the program here.
        //process.exit(0)
    }
  })
}

Main run function which calls the defined functions above to issue the credential to the holder.
const run = async () => {
  console.log('Initializing Bob agent (holder)...')
  const holder = await initializeBobAgent()

  console.log('Initializing Acme agent (issuer)...')
  const issuer = await initializeAcmeAgent()

  console.log('Creating the invitation as Acme...')
  const { outOfBandRecord, invitationUrl } = await createNewInvitation(issuer)

  console.log('Listening for connection changes...')
  setupConnectionListener(issuer, outOfBandRecord, async (cID) => {
    console.log('We now have an active connection to use')
    
  })

  console.log('Listening for credentials offers from the issuer...')
  setupCREDListener(holder)

  console.log('Accepting the connection invitation as Bob (holder)...')
  await receiveInvitation(holder, invitationUrl)


  // After connection is established between two agents, we import the published DID of the issuer into its agent.

  // Publishing DID
  const seed = TypedArrayEncoder.fromString(`acme0000000000000000000000000000`) // What you input on bcovrin. Should be kept secure in production!
  const unqualifiedIndyDid = `8QUXHgWMmgCjGFJ5bVCDxR` // will be returned after registering seed on bcovrin
  const indyDid = `did:indy:bcovrin:test:${unqualifiedIndyDid}`


  await issuer.dids.import({
    did: indyDid,
    overwrite: true,
    privateKeys: [
      {
        privateKey: seed,
        keyType: KeyType.Ed25519,
      },
    ],
  });

  console.log('DID created and imported into the isuuer agent successfully:', indyDid);


  // Publish schema
  const schemaResult = await issuer.modules.anoncreds.registerSchema({
    schema: {
      attrNames: ['name'],
      issuerId: indyDid,
      name: 'Example Schema to register by acme',
      version: '1.0.0',
    },
    options: {},
  })

  if (schemaResult.schemaState.state === 'failed') {
    throw new Error(`Error creating schema: ${schemaResult.schemaState.reason}`)
    return;
  } else {
    console.log("Schema definition is registered successfully:", schemaResult.schemaState.schema)
  }

  // Publish credential definition
  const credentialDefinitionResult = await issuer.modules.anoncreds.registerCredentialDefinition({
    credentialDefinition: {
      tag: 'default',
      issuerId: indyDid,
      schemaId: schemaResult.schemaState.schemaId!,
    },
    options: {
      supportRevocation: false,
    },
  })

  if (credentialDefinitionResult.credentialDefinitionState.state === 'failed') {
    throw new Error(
      `Error creating credential definition: ${credentialDefinitionResult.credentialDefinitionState.reason}`
    )
  } else {
    console.log("Credential definition is registered successfully", credentialDefinitionResult.credentialDefinitionState.credentialDefinition)
  }

  // Print statements for debugging...
  console.log("CredDefID: ", credentialDefinitionResult.credentialDefinitionState.credentialDefinitionId)
  console.log("outOfBandInvitation.id: ", outOfBandRecord.outOfBandInvitation.id)
  console.log("conID: ", conID!)


// Send credential offer to the holder agent.
  const indyCredentialExchangeRecord = await issuer.credentials.offerCredential({
    protocolVersion: 'v2',
    connectionId: conID!,
    credentialFormats: {
      indy: {
        credentialDefinitionId: credentialDefinitionResult.credentialDefinitionState.credentialDefinitionId!,
        attributes: [
          { name: 'name', value: 'Jane Doe' },
        ],
      },
    },
  })

  console.log("cred exchange state: ", indyCredentialExchangeRecord.state)
  console.log("cred err msg if any: ", indyCredentialExchangeRecord.errorMessage)
  try {
    // Get all credentials
    const credentialRecords = await holder.credentials.getAll();

    // Log or process the credentials
    console.log('All credentials:', credentialRecords);
    
    return credentialRecords;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch credentials:', error);
    throw error;
  }


}

export default run

void run()

The console output of the code:
Initializing Bob agent...
Initializing Acme agent...
Creating the invitation as Acme...
Listening for connection changes...
Listening for cred offers...
Accepting the invitation as Bob...
DID created and imported into the agent successfully: did:indy:bcovrin:test:8QUXHgWMmgCjGFJ5bVCDxR
Connection for out-of-band id 009bd8c4-6c7c-464b-ba9a-19e9613fb08d completed
We now have an active connection to use
Schema definition is registered successfully: {
  attrNames: [ 'name' ],
  issuerId: 'did:indy:bcovrin:test:8QUXHgWMmgCjGFJ5bVCDxR',
  name: 'Example Schema to register by acme',
  version: '1.0.0'
}
Credential definition is registered successfully {
  schemaId: 'did:indy:bcovrin:test:8QUXHgWMmgCjGFJ5bVCDxR/anoncreds/v0/SCHEMA/Example Schema to register by acme/1.0.0',
  type: 'CL',
  tag: 'default',
  value: {
    primary: {
      n: '121700781605622757139226254330243428133010676981620386744703620242802972805660749448580732878212001042062424351686060459850270454457698344161578593033755535125698990982697556347863231817386660568002872199699990404387241350140420241110390537520787100679715965709150205921738926902163945750726131681567691420582242905094236577619951916687052124321631620603485135222828328971637166311173519228425711306216630439277551198568314575399829525192722204688180750974978738349568325466983605607607756538543045630614520713503311277224192922541099560383007122066534774649026430221516369887761646388610946813118344227011732462420521',
      s: '17416359789599467653608807217630199161378524543614984752967689958244639814458492872495228210370771782029662567830838362041650917920406011875536782885373492526164294340089509941658695594483993192199247721860705395955758673482145948295707438624916008184879420972016011619356306800205068599914368678246822154454902897103354819726755814557894940804932710323952726904859894326830505241818883175176982456038690856398602448265640097439979599918756923545205371389280968459285670038285501765856499447670362411776693155512834066262074241752816855705314362533486681964515245168579094135112067540017391181083128676233762385849877',
      r: [Object],
      rctxt: '73804459258235220403808772726453438493152373201784466972269337926509957273019532038196786691879261928531155179316958230466815039652135144886937501637381901543405746474945939218032854652860235618622815072417052521517368067193009155194850136077920013268385715729493933607436754051342461901898945795939242814157270495477357591366102352530704474393483318971783016009610506823775186934506437442969296683965873208165511532014587581509664413032075256446287348578659386232677958234952037810389385251615641479022264335010520285886322494205968896375780915604463978387891559276866825933486492819083054262062284969594226603025811',
      z: '90765603271205090404241933638404859922838432752580885645685410109397057539010815729391442219815822413584583039122002211041223092856251146081674722923307943555094110615001119918585467322419252332011345278037964456305337755214401390958597435883534622410338343486955835986274387886379225092823050288813304838033415494484278194867291608207055207423823365371423667146315342344087134517078644471662122956143543457087719820243905690516339758095498984532193274002892094976117107195503467327270740778237700426856666755268026028184396242737879960729441631975219969666408391426877802534713677179409299285843732425678087729696589'
    }
  },
  issuerId: 'did:indy:bcovrin:test:8QUXHgWMmgCjGFJ5bVCDxR'
}
CredDefID:  did:indy:bcovrin:test:8QUXHgWMmgCjGFJ5bVCDxR/anoncreds/v0/CLAIM_DEF/112/default
outOfBandInvitation.id:  cece40a0-525b-487c-97bb-cd95fce999af
conID:  9abdd8d3-1aac-41d0-94db-885f4b397aec
cred exchange state:  offer-sent
cred err msg if any:  undefined
All credentials: []

Transaction on VON network to publish issuer DID:
VON network-publish issuer DID
Transaction to publish credential schema:
VON - publish schema
Transaction to publish credential definition:
VON network-publish credential definiton

Try with a different endpoints.
The 'endpoints' and 'agent.registerInboundTransport(new HttpInboundTransport({ port: 3001 })' seem to be clashing here. We usually have a separate agentEndpoint (here we start the API endpoint) and HttpInboudTransport(to receive incoming messages).
Try having a separate endpoints. Something like(3001, 3002) for issuer and (3003, 3004) for holder

I tried it but it gives error:
/home/onur/Desktop/ts-test/node_modules/@credo-ts/core/build/agent/MessageSender.js:293
throw new error_1.MessageSendingError(Message is undeliverable to connection ${connection.id} (${connection.theirLabel}), { outboundMessageContext });
^
MessageSendingError: Message is undeliverable to connection 985e34bb-5964-499c-9b53-45c28f87de6e (demo-agent-acma)
